# Combobox SelectedItem doesn't update when ItemsSource changes MVVM

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, combobox, observablecollection

I have an OvserableCollection of Aperture defined in the mainviewmodel

MainViewModel

```
public ObservableCollection<LookupItemViewModel> Apertures { get; }



public void LoadAperturesCollection()
        {
            Apertures.Clear();
            var items = _apertureTableListService.GetAllApertures();
            Apertures.Add(new LookupItemViewModel(0, null, true));
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                Apertures.Add(new LookupItemViewModel(item.Id, item.DisplayName, item.Active));
            }

            SessionViewModel.LoadActiveCollection(Apertures, nameof(Apertures));
        }
```

I have an ObservableCollection of ActiveApertures in the editviewmodel - this is a collection from the Apertures that has the field Active set to true

EditViewModel

```
public ObservableCollection<LookupItemViewModel> ActiveApertures { get; }



private void LoadActiveAperturesCollection(ObservableCollection<LookupItemViewModel> collection)
        {
            ActiveApertures.Clear();
            foreach (var item in collection)
            {
                if (item.Active)
                {
                    ActiveApertures.Add(new LookupItemViewModel(item.Id, item.DisplayName, item.Active));
                }
            }
        }
```

The Exposure table has a property of Aperture that is a foreign key to the Aperture table

In the exposureeditview is a combobox with an ItemsSource of ActiveApertures

ExposureEditView

```
<ComboBox 
            x:Name="comboBoxExposureDataAperture"
            Grid.Column="3"
            Grid.Row="5"
            DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName"
            IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
            IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
            IsTextSearchCaseSensitive="True"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ActiveApertures}"
            SelectedValue="{Binding Exposure.ApertureId, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
            SelectedValuePath="Id"
            Style="{DynamicResource ComboboxData}"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
            Width="110"
            Margin="0,0,0,5"/>
```

If I edit an Aperture, the Apertures collection is updated, and the ActiveApertures collection is updated, but the SelectedItem in the combobox is now empty. All of the viewmodels implement INotifyPropertyChanged().

I've been searching the internet, but I've yet to find a solution that matches this problem.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

EDIT 1

```
 private LookupItemViewModel selectedRecord;
        public LookupItemViewModel SelectedRecord
        {
            get { return selectedRecord; }
            set
            {
                if(value != selectedRecord)
                {
                    selectedRecord = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
                
            }
        }

<ComboBox 
            x:Name="comboBoxExposureDataAperture"
            Grid.Column="3"
            Grid.Row="5"
            DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName"
            IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
            IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
            IsTextSearchCaseSensitive="True"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ActiveApertures}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRecord}"
            SelectedValue="{Binding Exposure.ApertureId, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
            SelectedValuePath="Id"
            Style="{DynamicResource ComboboxData}"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
            Width="110"
            Margin="0,0,0,5"/>

 protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
```

EDIT2

```
 public void LoadAperturesCollection()
        {
            Apertures.Clear();
            var items = _apertureTableListService.GetAllApertures();
            Apertures.Add(new LookupItemViewModel(0, null, true));
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                Apertures.Add(new LookupItemViewModel(item.Id, item.DisplayName, item.Active));
            }

            SessionViewModel.LoadActiveCollection(Apertures, nameof(Apertures));
        }

private void LoadActiveAperturesCollection(ObservableCollection<LookupItemViewModel> collection)
        {
            ActiveApertures.Clear();
            foreach (var item in collection)
            {
                if (item.Active)
                {
                    ActiveApertures.Add(new LookupItemViewModel(item.Id, item.DisplayName, item.Active));
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to update the SelectedItem using an AfterDataSaved event.

Thanks to everyone trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

So why not bind `SelectItem` in `Combobox`?

If you have implemented the `INotifyPropertyChanged` in viewModel,Create an sample of an ActiveApertures item called **SelectedRecord** and bind it to the `ComboBox`. change it as shown below

`EditViewModel` change to :

```
public class EditViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<LookupItemViewModel> ActiveApertures { get; }
    private LookupItemViewModel _selectedRecord;
    public LookupItemViewModel SelectedRecord
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedRecord;
        }
        set
        {
            if(value != _selectedRecord)
            {
                _selectedRecord = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedRecord");
            }
        }
    }
    /.............................................................
    /.............................................................
    /.............................................................
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }  
}
```

Change `ComboBox` to :

```
<ComboBox 
            x:Name="comboBoxExposureDataAperture"
            Grid.Column="3"
            Grid.Row="5"
            DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName"
            IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
            IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
            IsTextSearchCaseSensitive="True"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ActiveApertures}"
            SelectedValue="{Binding Exposure.ApertureId, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
            SelectedValuePath="Id"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRecord}"
            Style="{DynamicResource ComboboxData}"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
            Width="110"
            Margin="0,0,0,5"/>
```

Comment: Meysam, I made the changes you suggested, but I'm having the same issue. Setting a break point, the SelectedRecord get is called, but the set is never accessed.

Comment: Any other suggestions?

Comment: I have the SelectedItem binding working (incorrect ViewModel). But when the SelectedRecord property is called, the ActiveApertures collection is null. In EDIT2 I have an example of the code to update the Apertures and ActiveApertures collections when an Aperture entry is changed.

Comment: Give a constructor to your view model and in it ActiveApertures = new ObservableCollection<LookupItemViewModel>();

Comment: I new an ObservableCollection<LookupItemViewModel>() in the viewmodel.  Apertures = new ObservableCollection<LookupItemViewModel>();